# When I create a comment it will only display after reloading the page. I use redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

This is my Comment Slice code which I have created to dispatch the add comment:

```
   // commentReducer.js

    import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

    const commentSlice = createSlice({
      name: 'comment',
      initialState: [],
      reducers: {
        addComment: (state, action) => {
          state.push(action.payload);
        },
      },
    });

    export const { addComment } = commentSlice.actions;
    export default commentSlice.reducer;
```

This is the code where I implemented the function to add comment to my MongoDB server. I want to display after adding but it will only display after reloading the page:

```
 Comment.jsx:
    import axios from "axios";
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    import styled from "styled-components";
    import Comment from "./Comment";
    import { addComment } from "../redux/commentSlice";

    const Container = styled.div``;

    const NewComment = styled.div`
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 10px;
    `;

    const Avatar = styled.img`
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
    `;

    const Input = styled.input`
      border: none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.soft};
      color: ${({ theme }) => theme.text};
      background-color: transparent;
      outline: none;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 100%;
    `;

    const Button = styled.button`
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color:#453af6;
        border-radius: 5px;
        height: max-content;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        &:hover{
            background-color: #497cf6;
        }
    `

    const Comments = ({videoId}) => {

      const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
      const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
      const [desc, setDesc] = useState([]);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();



      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchComments = async () => {
          try {
            const res = await axios.get(`/comments/${videoId}`);
            setComments(res.data);
          } catch (err) {}
        };
        fetchComments();
      }, [videoId]);

      const handlePost = async (e) => {
        if (currentUser) {
          e.preventDefault();
          const res = await axios.post('/comments/', { desc, videoId });
          dispatch(addComment(desc));
        }
        if (!currentUser) {
          alert('Please sign in to post a comment');
        }
      };


      return (
        <Container>
          <NewComment>
            <Avatar src={currentUser?.img} />
            <Input placeholder="Add a comment..."
            onChange={(e)=> setDesc(e.target.value)}
            />
            <Button onClick={handlePost}>Comment</Button>
          </NewComment>
          {comments.map(comment=>(
            <Comment key={comment._id} comment={comment}/>
          ))}
        </Container>
      );
    };

    export default Comments;
```

This is my store:

```
    import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
    import userReducer from './userSlice';
    import videoReducer from './videoSlice';
    import commentReducer from './commentSlice';
    import {
      persistStore,
      persistReducer,
      FLUSH,
      REHYDRATE,
      PAUSE,
      PERSIST,
      PURGE,
      REGISTER,
    } from 'redux-persist'
    import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
    import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'


    const persistConfig = {
      key: 'root',
      version: 1,
      storage,
    }

    const rootReducer = combineReducers({user: userReducer, video: videoReducer, comment: commentReducer});

    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)


    export const store = configureStore({
      reducer: persistedReducer,
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
          serializableCheck: {
            ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
          },
        }),

    }) ;
    export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

It should display without reloading the page. Please review my code